# Change CSS of inner div when scroll reaches that div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am attempting to implement a scroll function where the CSS of the inner div's change when it reaches a certain height from the top.

```js
var $container = $(".inner-div");
var containerTop = $container.offset().top;
var documentTop = $(document).scrollTop();
var wHeight = $(window).height();
var minMaskHeight = 0;
var descriptionMax = 200;
var logoMin = -200;
var maskDelta = descriptionMax - minMaskHeight;
var $jobOverview = $container.find(".right");
var $jobLogo = $container.find(".left");

var curPlacementPer = ((containerTop - documentTop) / wHeight) * 100;
var topMax = 85;
var center = 20;
var bottomMax = -15;

//console.log("Placement: " + curPlacementPer);

function applyChanges(perOpen) {
  var maskHeightChange = maskDelta * (perOpen / 100);
  var opacityPer = perOpen / 100;
  var newDescriptionLeft = descriptionMax - maskHeightChange;
  var newLogoLeft = logoMin + maskHeightChange;
  if (newDescriptionLeft <= 0) newDescriptionLeft = 0;
  if (newLogoLeft >= 0) newLogoLeft = 0;
  if (opacityPer >= 1) opacityPer = 1;
  $jobOverview.css({
    transform: "translate(" + newDescriptionLeft + "%,-50%)",
    opacity: opacityPer
  });
  $jobLogo.css({
    transform: "translate(" + newLogoLeft + "%,-50%)",
    opacity: opacityPer
  });
}

if (window.innerWidth > 640) {
  $container.removeClass("mobile");
  // console.log("Placement: " + curPlacementPer);

  if (curPlacementPer <= topMax /*&& curPlacementPer >= center*/ ) {
    var perOpen = ((topMax - curPlacementPer) / 25) * 100;
    applyChanges(perOpen);
  } else if (curPlacementPer < center /*&& curPlacementPer >= bottomMax*/ ) {
    var perOpen = (((bottomMax - curPlacementPer) * -1) / 25) * 100;
    applyChanges(perOpen);
  } else {
    $jobOverview.css({
      transform: "translate(200%,-50%)",
      opacity: "0"
    });
    $jobLogo.css({
      transform: "translate(-300%,-50%)",
      opacity: "0"
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div first">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div second">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div third">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div fourth">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, all of the inner div's gets changed at the same time.
I noticed that when I change the `$container` class to equal `'.first'` and specify it more, it works.

Is there any way to make the inner div's change separately, relative to its height from the top? Any way I can iterate the scroll function so I can add more inner div's in the future and not have to worry about changing my scroll function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider using 3rd party jQuery plugin for easier job, like one of these:

> **https://github.com/xobotyi/jquery.viewport**
>
> or
>
> **https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport**

then you can have additional element selector e.g.: `":in-viewport"`

so you can:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {
    $('div').not(':in-viewport').html('');
    $('div:in-viewport').html('hello');
});
```

Comment: Really a nice answer.

Answer (score 5):

In raw JavaScript, this is my answer:

```
// Define the element -- The '#fooBar' can be changed to anything else.
var element = document.querySelector("#fooBar");

// Define how much of the element is shown before something happens.
var scrollClipHeight = 0 /* Whatever number value you want... */;

// Function to change an element's CSS when it is scrolled in.
const doSomething = function doSomething() {

    /** When the window vertical scroll position plus the
     *   window's inner height has reached the
     *   top position of your element.
    */
    if (
           (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) - (scrollClipHeight || 0) >= 
           element.getBoundingClientRect().top
    )
        // Generally, something is meant to happen here.
        element.style = "/* Yay, some CSS! */"
};

// Call the function without an event occurring.
doSomething();

// Call the function when the 'window' scrolls.
addEventListener("scroll", doSomething, false)
```

This is the method I use. If there are other methods, I'd love to see them as well but this is my answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

Check if current scroll offset from top is bigger than the element offset from the top:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    var element = $('#changethis'); //change this to your element you want to add the css to
    if(height  > element.offset().top) {
        element.addClass('black'); //add css class black (change according to own css)
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="changethis">Test</div>
```

Css:

```
body
{
height:2000px;

}
.black
{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  padding:20px;
}
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZdEap

You could easily implement this in your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample snippet code, Hope it'll work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 topMax = 100;
  topMin = 25;
  $(document).scroll(function(){
    $('.inner-div').each(function(){  
     if($(this).offset().top-$(window).scrollTop()<=topMax && $(this).offset().top-$(window).scrollTop()>=topMin){
       $(this).css({'background':'#c7c7c7'});
      }else{
       $(this).css({'background':'inherit'});
      }
   });
  });  
});
```

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
div.inner-div{
  border: 1px dashed green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div first">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div second">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div third">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-div fourth">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Happy to help you! :)